# What would cause the whole screen to display stats?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

when i RDP to a machine, my whole screen looks like this:
[image]
Why? I did re-start that server, and it did not fix the issue.

Comment: What OS are you remoting from / to?

Comment: Can you try a different browser? Or a different web page?

Comment: It's just a website not the OS your question is misleading

Comment: The OS actually matters because you are running over RDP. Depending on the OS, then different versions of RDP might be used. This particular problem is called "client cache poisoning" and is an artifact of RDP (and you will notice that this happens only on your machine connecting to the server). Depending on the RDP versions, different fixes might be required.

Answer (score 0):

The fix should be performed on the client machine (the one connecting to the remote server). In order for the fix to be successful, please first disconnect ***any MSTSC / Remote Desktop sessions*** and wait for at least 30 seconds.

After 30 seconds, please open File Explorer (explorer.exe) and go to `%appdata%\..\Local\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Cache` and delete all the files. Once you have done that, you can attempt to reconnect.

Can you please also share the OS that you are connecting from?